# Tasks vs Threads in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net

Well in `.Net 4`, There is the new Tasks feature and i was wondering if i can rely on it alog with `Async/Await` in `.Net 4.5` for all the method(s) that i want to execute asynchronously or there are some situations that i will have to use a separate `Thread`, specially that i have read that Task.Run uses a `ThreadPool` to execute the method asynchronously.

Conclusion : Is using a combination of `Async/Await` along with `Tasks` can free me of using `Threads` ?

Comment: It completely depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @SLaks so can you clarify it for me by telling me when should i trigger a new Thread to do my work and when a ThreadPool (Which is the Task.Run) is enough ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specify the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option (there is an equivalent for continuations as well) then the task will not use a thread pool thread, it will use a regular `Thread`.  Technically this is an implementation detail and is not in the specs, but it's not a completely unreasonable assumption to rely on.

Given that, you should be able to do anything using `Task` that you could do with `Thread` directly.

The primary case that comes to mind for where someone might want to use `Thread` directly would be in creating your own parallel library, assuming you choose not to build it on top of the TPL.  While it's not significant in the context of a business application, when creating your own library you may need access to underlying details of a specific `Thread` object, or you may want to avoid the overhead (small as it is) of using `Tasks`.

And then of course, if you're not yet using .NET 4.0 you don't have the option of using `Task`.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 Also can i am not going to create a library all my work these days is on creating applications for various things so i want to easiest yet most powerful way to finish all my codes elegantly. So can i conclude from what you are saying that i can do whatever is done using Thread using a Task ? Also is it possible to get all the asynchronous work done only by using Tasks in combination with Async/Await ?. And thanks for you immediate detailed answer.

Comment: +1 I would recommend the LongRunning option for tasks that you'd normally use with Thread so you can get async/await easily.  There's other ways of not using ThreadPool threads; but, they don't really buy you much now with async/await

Comment: @PeterRitchie: But just to confirm my knowledge is async await is designed just to make a method awaitable so the program do not processed to the next line of code before it just finish the current awaited job is that right or there are another uses of Async/Await ?

Comment: `async` makes a method awaitable as well as able to await other awaitables (they don't have to be methods).  Awaiting on a method may or may not mean something occurs asynchronously.

Comment: For example, if you await on a completed task, that will occur synchronously because the task has nothing more to do.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: So Async/Await does not turn a method to an async method by itself, either i should use Task.Run to make it asynchronous right ?

Comment: One nice thing with async/await is that using `await Task.Delay` makes it much easier to create a 'polling' thread without having to tie up a long-running thread using Thread.Sleep.  I've found that this eliminates the vast majority of cases where I wanted to create dedicated long-running threads.

Comment: @runes yes, it's up to the method to do something asynchronous.  That usually means awaiting something else, or returning a Task...

Comment: @DanBryant: Right i have discovered this thing recently and i am using it instead of Thread.Sleep.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: Well i am starting to feel better with that very detailed discussion thank you guys very much and excuse me if i was asking too much because i just wanna to learn and accept me to ask again if i did got some questions.